# Window's PID of the current emacs' process

Tags: process, pdf-tools

I use to edit `LaTeX` documents with `okular` as pdf viewer in Ubuntu Linux. I have this code:

```
(defun okular-forward-search ()
  (interactive)
  (start-process
   "okular"
   "okular-output"
   "okular" ;;; src-args
    ;;; args for -sourceposition:
   "--unique"
   (concat
    "file:"
    (concat (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) ".pdf")
    "#src:"
    (number-to-string (line-number-at-pos (point)))
    (buffer-file-name))))
```

that performs forward-search from `LaTeX` code in `emacs` to the corresponding page in the generated `.pdf` file. My problem is that this shift the "focus" from `emacs` to `okular` and this is, for me, very annoying.

Is there a hack to keep the focus on emacs?

**EDIT**
I modified the function:

```
(defun okular-forward-search-mod ()
  (interactive)
  (call-process-shell-command
   (concat "okular --unique file:" (concat (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) ".pdf")
       "#src:"
       (number-to-string (line-number-at-pos (point)))
       (buffer-file-name))
   )
  (call-process-shell-command "wmctrl -a emacs"))
```

But I still have an issue. If more instances of `emacs` are open the focus is on the first opened.
How can I get the window PID of the current `emacs`' process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem rewriting my function:

```
(defun okular-forward-search-mod ()
  (interactive)
  (setq PID (number-to-string (emacs-pid)))
  (call-process-shell-command
   (concat "okular --unique file:" (concat (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) ".pdf")
       "#src:"
       (number-to-string (line-number-at-pos (point)))
       (buffer-file-name))
   )
  (call-process-shell-command (concat "wmctrl -ia $(wmctrl -lp | awk -vpid=$PID '$3=="
                      PID
                      " {print $1; exit}')"))
)
```

It seems to work fine.

I found some hints here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45154/switch-to-an-application-using-its-pid