# Get process id for the Emacs own process

Tags: process

I'm supporting some elisp code that creates a temporary filename using a prefix and the user id. When I develop this, that is not enough since I will be running multiple instances concurrently.

So I'm looking for either a function to create a temporary filename which I can control to some extent, or some other component to add to the name.

I thought the second option should be straightforward so I looked at `process-id`, but that requires a *process*. (elisp manual: [Process Information](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Process-Information.html))

So I looked at `get-process` but that requires a *name*, which would also be ambiguous.

How do I get the process id for the running Emacs process?

EDIT: I solved my problem using `make-temp-name` (yeah, I know I should not use it, but I don't want to change the handling of temporary files at this point).

But for my edification, is there a way to get the process id for the Emacs process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I do understand correctly you could use `(emacs-pid)`

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Where in the elisp manual should I have looked?

Comment: System Interface > System Environment

Comment: And I should probably have found this: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32398/windows-pid-of-the-current-emacs-process

Comment: I've found ivy  very useful to quickly find functions by name or parts of the name, BTW

Comment: You mean https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper?

Comment: Yes, it¡s a three-part completion mechanism.